# PLSQL Quoted String Not Properly Terminated

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle10g

I am unable to find the error with a quoted string not properly ended.  I've looked everywhere and my syntax seems to be correct.  The issue only came about when I introduced the if statement.  Any ideas would be appreciated.  Thanks.  Let me know if you need more information.

```
declare

bk_id book.book_code%type;
bk_authorName author.author_first%type;
bk_authorLastName author.author_last%type;
bk_title book.title%type;
bk_pubcode book.publisher_code%type;
bk_category book.type%type;
bk_price book.price%type;
bk_paper book.paperback%type;
TempData := 10;

cursor book_cursor is select author.author_first, author.author_last,  book.title, book.type, book.price from book, author, wrote where book.book_code=wrote.book_code and author.author_num=wrote.author_num;

begin

open book_cursor;

dbms_output.put_line('First Name    Last Name       Title                        Type    Price');
dbms_output.put_line('________________________________________________________________________');
dbms_output.put_line('Date: '||Systimestamp);
loop

fetch book_cursor into  bk_authorName, bk_authorLastName, bk_title, bk_category, bk_price;

if(bk_price<TempData) then

dbms_output.put_line(bk_authorName || ' ' || bk_authorLastName || ' ' || bk_title || ' ' || bk_category || ' ' || bk_price || 'Special Deal');

else

dbms_output.put_line(bk_authorName || ' ' || bk_authorLastName || ' ' || bk_title || ' " || bk_category || ' ' || bk_price);

end if;

exit when book_cursor%notfound;

end loop;

close book_cursor;

end;
```

Comment: Just looking at the syntax highlighting is enough to see where your typo is...

Comment: I do not have syntax highlighting in the Mac terminal.  Where do you see it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo

Comment: @Klinetel: there's syntax highlighting here.

Comment: I still do not see the error, could you please kindly point it out?

Comment: There is a double quote rather than a single quote before `bk_category` in the ELSE clause.

Comment: Thanks!  Terrible mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem with this syntax is you used double quotes instead of single quotes.
This is the corrected code. Try this,it should work.

```
    declare

    bk_id book.book_code%type;
    bk_authorName author.author_first%type;
    bk_authorLastName author.author_last%type;
    bk_title book.title%type;
    bk_pubcode book.publisher_code%type;
    bk_category book.type%type;
    bk_price book.price%type;
    bk_paper book.paperback%type;
    TempData := 10;

    cursor book_cursor is select author.author_first, author.author_last,  book.title, book.type, book.price from book, author, wrote where book.book_code=wrote.book_code and author.author_num=wrote.author_num;

    begin

    open book_cursor;

    dbms_output.put_line('First Name    Last Name       Title                        Type    Price');
    dbms_output.put_line('________________________________________________________________________');
    dbms_output.put_line('Date: '||Systimestamp);
    loop

    fetch book_cursor into  bk_authorName, bk_authorLastName, bk_title, bk_category, bk_price;

    if(bk_price<TempData) then

    dbms_output.put_line(bk_authorName || ' ' || bk_authorLastName || ' ' || bk_title || ' ' || bk_category || ' ' || bk_price || 'Special Deal');

    else

    dbms_output.put_line(bk_authorName || ' ' || bk_authorLastName || ' ' || bk_title || ' ' || bk_category || ' ' || bk_price);

    end if;

    exit when book_cursor%notfound;

    end loop;

    close book_cursor;

    end;
```